# Can anyone please explain me the direction of static friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, vectors, free-body-diagram

I cannot understand that how can the frictional force applied a box on a conveyor belt be in the same direction of motion? How is frictional force responsible for the forward movement of a box on conveyor belt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friction opposes the actual or impending motion of an object.  For the box on the belt, as the belt moves forward, without friction the box would move backwards relative to the belt.  Friction opposes this backward motion of the box, thereby moving the box forward.  (Once the belt and box are moving at constant velocity, there is no force of friction on the box.)

Answer (score 2):

Friction does not oppose motion in general. It opposes slipping, which is the relative motion of two surfaces that are in contact.

In the case of the conveyor belt, if the box remains stationary then it will slip. In order to not slip the box must move together with the belt. That requires a force in the direction of motion to accelerate, and once it is done accelerating then there will be no more force needed.